# Interactive 3D plot with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, plot, 3d

I have been using `plotly` for dataframe visualisation, but when the data type is array, what is the best way to create an interactive plot, apart from converting array into dataframe?

Code I previously used for dataframe:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='col1', y='col2', z='col3',)

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=2,
                         line=dict(width=0.01)
                             )
                 )

fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, 
                  width=900, 
                  height=900,
                  title = 'My Plot')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you have a numpy array whose columns (or rows) give the coordinates of points you want to plot, then you can assign these columns to the `x`, `y` and `z` arguments:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 3))
fig = px.scatter_3d(x=X[:,0], y=X[:, 1], z=X[:, 2])
fig.show()
```